# Difference between distance between two points and metric

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry

if i have a line element given e.g. $ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{2y} $ is it then always possible to derive a distance between two points in this metric? and how would one determine the length of a curve if only the line element is given?

Comment: You didn't do you duty ! Always check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_metric) before asking !

Comment: In general an explicit formula might be hard to find. I suggest that you read about the hyperbolic metric, and carry out the corresponding analysis here. In particular, you can calculate the Christoffel symbols and the geodesics. Then, if the geodesics look nice enough, you can try to get a formula for the length. I am guessing that under suitable parametrization the vertical lines will be geodesics. If that is the case, you will have an explicit formula for points having the same $y$-coordinates.